# Push modified/new files to an existing git repo (bitbucket)

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I created a new repo on Bitbucket and pushed local files into it a while ago.

Now that I've done some changes to the local files, I created a new tag via:

```
$ git tag 1.0.1
```

then tried to upload all local files into the repo with:

```
$ git push
```

It said "everything's up to date" and did nothing. Then I tried to push them with:

```
$ git push origin 1.0.1
```

with not luck again and the same error message. What did I miss?

Comment: Did you make a commit with the changes?

Comment: @crea1 Thanks, seems like I've missed that part.